# Cycle through an array in either direction based on a bool

Tags: c

I'm looking for a method of looping through some array in either direction based on some passed bool value, with the same functionality as:

```c
void Transfer(bool *_payload, int _size, bool _isLSB)
{
    if (_isLSB)
    {
        for (int i = _size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            digitalWrite(dataPin, _payload[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        {
            digitalWrite(dataPin, _payload[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

or

```c
void Transfer(bool *_payload, int _size, bool _isLSB)
{
    int _index = 0;
    if (_isLSB) _index = _size - 1;
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("%d",_payload[_index]);
        if (_isLSB) _index--;
        else _index++;
        if (_isLSB && _index < 0) break;
        if (!_isLSB && _index >= _size) break;
    }
}
```

Other than creating a method that reverses the array, is there a nice simplification of this?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude My mistake, I'll update it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the starting and ending point *and* the increment conditionally:

```
void Transfer(bool *_payload, int _size, bool _isLSB)
{
    int increment = _isLSB ? -1 : 1;
    int i = _isLSB ? _size : -1;      // one before the area to scan
    int end = _isLSB ? -1 : _size;    // one past the area

    while ((i += increment) != end)   // incr/decr before testing
    {
        digitalWrite(dataPin, _payload[i]);
    }
}
```

We do not know in advance which way the index will be changing (incrementing or decrementing), so we can't use less-than or greater-than in the loop condition. And after processing the last item the index will be modified once more, hence the stopping point is one past the area being processed.

Similarly we need the starting point one position before the scanned area, so that after incrementing (or decrementing) the index we process the valid, first item.

Comment: Just a note: While this does work for this specific case, there could be problems if in the use case `end` would not be exactly one value or could be missed.

Comment: @DJSchaffner What value of type `int` is _'not exactly one value'_...?

Comment: When the increment is not `1` and may never hit the end point exactly for example

Comment: @DJSchaffner I guess you mean something like iteration over e.g. floating-point numbers. But, TBH, I never met an array which was indexed with a non-integral type. Certainly, every problem can be generalized and then some specific application can be found within a generalization, which breaks any chosen implementation assumption previously made. But we do not solve _EVERYTHING_ here. We solve iteration over a relatively short, `int`–indexed array, based at index `0` and with known size. And my solution, as far as I am aware, fits these constraints. If it does not, please let me know,

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the direction and the start/end position for the `for` loop depending on `_isLSB`

```
void Transfer(bool* _payload, int _size, bool _isLSB) {
    int dir;
    int start;
    int end;
    if(_isLSB) {
        dir = -1;
        start = _size-1;
        end = -1;
    }else {
        dir = 1;
        start = 0;
        end = _size;
    }
    for(int i = start; i != end; i+=dir) {
        digitalWrite(dataPin, _payload[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: @CiaPan Thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do for example, since in C `true` and `false` are expanded to integer values in reality, is to use said integer value for calculations.
In the following example I will extract the main problem from your question which is: Looping over a size in a direction depending on a boolean value

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int size = 5;
    bool condition = false;

    // Option #1
    printf("Option #1\n");

    for (int i = (size - 1) * condition; (i >= 0 && condition) || (i < size && !condition); i += 1 * pow(-1, condition))
    {
        printf("%d", i);
    }

    // Option #2
    printf("\nOption #2\n");

    int i = (size - 1) * condition;
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("%d", i);
        i += 1 * pow(-1, condition);
        
        if ((i < 0 && condition) || (i >= size && !condition))
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With the main function giving the following output for `condition = true`

> Option #1
> 01234
> Option #2
> 01234

And the following output for `condition = false`

> Option #1
> 43210
> Option #2
> 43210

Comment: Are you sure you need to check `condition` and `!condition` in the loops continue/break conditions...?  :) I suppose those conditions will be shorter, more efficient and more legible without using the `condition` variable.

Comment: @CiaPan Since there is theoretically no way of the index leaving the bounds in any direction you could leave those checks out if you like.